# Disable IP logging in IPB

Tags: logging, ip, ipb

I am using IPB 3.1.4, can you tell me which classes and methods am I need to remove to disable IP logging in forum?
I can't ask this question on specialized IPB forum because of I don't know where they are and stackoverflow is the best site of programmers and maybe someone know how to resolve my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres no way to disable ip logging without editing ipb source files. You can try to set same ip for all users. To do it try this:

1. open admin/sources/handlers/han_login.php
2. find this code: `if ( $member['ip_address'] == "" OR $member['ip_address'] == '127.0.0.1' )
   {
   $core['ip_address'] = $this->registry->member()->ip_address;
   }`
3. Replace it with this: `if ( $member['ip_address'] == "")
   {
   $core['ip_address'] = "127.0.0.1";
   }`
4. save

**P.S.** a lot of ipb functions (e.g. spam-protection, bruteforce-protection...) use ip. Do you really want to disable ip logging? It may cause a lot of troubles.

Comment: Thx I'll try it. And in which tables of DB IPB save IPs?

Comment: Np. 'ip_address' row in the 'members' table. Also ips are stored in 'posts' table.